# Just rebuild a Text Widget. but still takes up the same resources as rebuilding the entire screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I just tested with provider: 4.0.5, split textview to other class and use consumer to provide state for text rebuild, but maybe all widget have been rebuild also.
my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyState with ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  void incre() {
    counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => MyState(),
          child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.5,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        offset: Offset(-5, -5),
                        blurRadius: 25,
                        spreadRadius: 25)
                  ]),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Hello World',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.5,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        offset: Offset(-5, -5),
                        blurRadius: 25,
                        spreadRadius: 25)
                  ]),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Hello World',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.5,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        offset: Offset(-5, -5),
                        blurRadius: 25,
                        spreadRadius: 25)
                  ]),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Hello World',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.5,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        offset: Offset(-5, -5),
                        blurRadius: 25,
                        spreadRadius: 25)
                  ]),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Hello World',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 35,
            ),
            MyText(),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: Provider.of<MyState>(context, listen: false).incre,
//              onTap: () {
//                setState(() {});
//              },
              child: Text('click'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyState>(
      builder: (_, state, __) {
        print('buildText2');
        return Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times: ${state.counter}',
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is screen when I update and rebuild a Text only, but it's very expensive.
[image: Simulator Screen Shot - iPhone 11 Pro - 2020-04-26 at 20 06 45]

this is my flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.18.0-6.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-VN)
    • Flutter version 1.18.0-6.0.pre at /Users/tbm/dev/flutter_sdk/flutter
    • Framework revision 84c84fb249 (6 days ago), 2020-04-20 21:35:01 -0400
    • Engine revision 2bde4f0ae4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-1.0.dev a12c36dd97)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding unnecessary rebuilds optimizes the CPU time. Your issue is the rendering time, which is unaffected by the optimisation you made.

Your problem is that your UI is too complex to draw.

One of the reasons is: [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) is very expensive, and you used *a lot* of them.

Instead of doing:

```dart
Opacity(
  opacity: .5
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: .5
    child: ...
  ),
),
```

A first step would be to merge both [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) in a single one:

```dart
Opacity(
  opacity: .5 * .5
  child: ...
),
```

Then, for further optimisations, instead of:

```
[
  Opacity(
    opacity: .5 * .5
    child: A(),
  ),
  Opacity(
    opacity: .5 * .5
    child: B(),
  ),
  Something(),
]
```

You could have:

```dart
[
  Opacity(
    opacity: .5 * .5,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        A(),
        B(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  Something(),
]
```

Comment: Oh. I thought it was only expensive at the first build. and then there will be no cost if it does not rebuild. Maybe I was wrong: D. Thank you!